# How do I inherit element names from the current XSLT context?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<article properName="Article">
  <h1>
    This <strong>is a header</strong>
  </h1>
  <p>This is a <strong>paragraph</strong</p>
</article>
```

I need to convert that to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Article>
  <Article-bigheader>
    This <Article-bigheader-bold>is a header</Article-bigheader-bold>
  </Article-bigheader>
  <Article-paragraph>This is a <Article-paragraph-bold>paragraph</Article-paragraph-bold></Article-paragraph>
</Article>
```

The elements in the original document will have varying names and be nested in different ways, so I need to do this dynamically instead of creating an xsl template for every possible combination. The specific part I'm having a problem with is the text decoration, how do I create an element with the name of its containing XSLT element and the appended "-bold" suffix?
This is what I've got so far:

```
<xsl:template match="/article">
    <xsl:element name="{@properName}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="h1">
    <xsl:element name="{concat(/article/@properName, '-', 'bigheader')}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@properName]">
    <xsl:element name="{@properName}">
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="@properName"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:element name="{concat($name, '-', 'bigheader')}">
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="concat($name, '-', 'bigheader')"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:element name="{concat($name, '-', 'paragraph')}">
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="concat($name, '-', 'paragraph')"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="strong">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:element name="{concat($name, '-', 'bold')}">
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="concat($name, '-', 'bold')"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```